# using .on() Jquery function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this code is wrong. I want all `<p>` elements to get color `cornflowerblue` in my HTML when I put the mouse over a paragraph in my webpage.
I've done the same using other ways, but how could I do this using `on()`?

jQuery: I know there are other ways to do this but I want to try this one, using `on()`. I put a name to the function but I'm pretty sure that's not correct.

```
ChangeColorOnHover("p")
$(document).ready(function ChangeColorOnHover(elementtype) {
    $element = $(elementtype)
    $element
    .on({
        mouseenter: function (event) {
            var $this = $(this)
            $this.addClass(".IsHover")
        }
    })
    .on({
        mouseleave: function () {
            var $this = $(this)
            $this.removeClass(".IsHover")
        }
    })
})
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
p {
    color: tomato;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
p.IsHover{
    color:cornflowerblue;
}
```

HTML: (csstestview is the name of the external CSS file). HTML is recognizing that CSS file, I've probed that.

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/csstestview")  
<div id="firstdiv" class="divvv">
  <img src="/images/Soccer.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="soccer icon" />
  <p id="pp" class="pa"> this is a <em>paragraph</em></p>
  <p>paragraph testing</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding `$(document).ready`.  Your function doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var ChangeColorOnHover = function(elementtype) {
        //Select all elements
        $element = $(elementtype);
        //Set up event handlers
        $element.on('mouseenter', function() {
            //No need for . when adding a class
            $(this).addClass("IsHover");
        });
        $element.on('mouseleave', function() {
            //No need for . when removing a class
            $(this).removeClass("IsHover");
        });
    };

    //Call your function
    ChangeColorOnHover("p");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: When using `addClass` you don't need to put the `.` in `.isHover` just put `isHover`. If that doesn' work you can try doing: 
`$(event.target).addClass("isHover")`

Answer (score 1):

The current jQuery v2.2.3 has the .mouseenter() and .mouseleave() handler.
Based on your code this could be used as follows:

```
$element.mouseenter( function() { $(this).addClass('IsHover'); } );
$element.mouseleave( function() { $(this).removeClass('IsHover'); } );
```

Or you could just have CSS do all this for you. As an example in your CSS you could have:

```
p:hover { color: cornflowerblue; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define you named function outside statement `(...)`, and use `.on()` only once:

```js
function ChangeColorOnHover(elementtype) {
    var $element = $(elementtype);

    $element.on({
        mouseenter: function (event) {
            var $this = $(this)
            $this.addClass("IsHover")
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            var $this = $(this)
            $this.removeClass("IsHover")
        }
    })
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    ChangeColorOnHover("p")
})
```

```css
.container {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
max-width: 960px;
margin: 20px auto;
}
p {
    color: tomato;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
p.IsHover{
            color:cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: This answer is very comprehensive, thanks, I see that you placed the `$(document).ready(function())` outside and from there you called the ChangeColorFunction thanks to everybody!!

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by pure css. But this is what you are looking for.
[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nmsqfrqs/)

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseenter', 'p', function() {
    $(this).addClass('IsHover');
  }).on('mouseleave', 'p', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('IsHover');
  });
});
```

if you like to do this with a function you should declare the function outside the `$(function(){});`, then use the function inside as you want it to trigger when the site is loaded.

```
function changeColorOnHover(element) {
  $(document).on('mouseenter', element, function() {
    $(this).addClass('IsHover');
  }).on('mouseleave', element, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('IsHover');
  });
}

$(function() {
  changeColorOnHover('p');
});
```